# dynamic elements and listening for events on them

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a list of emails on a page.

```
 echo "<div class='comms'>";
 $sel = "SELECT * from emails where customerId=:custId";
 $stmt = $db->prepare($sel);
 $stmt->bindParam(':custId',$_POST['custId']);
 $stmt->execute();
 while($r = $stmt->fetch())
 {
    echo "<li class='emails'>" . $r['date']. " " . substr($r['data'],0,15) . "....</li>";
 }
 echo "</div>";
```

I also have an ajax call every minute to check for new email.

```
    var getMail = function(){
            var custId = "<?php echo $_POST['custId'];?>";
    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
                    url:"installManager/getMail.php",
                    data:"custId="+custId,
            success: function(result){
                    $('.comms').html(result);
            }
            });
    }
    var interval = 1000 * 60 * 1;
    setInterval(getMail,interval);
```

I am trying to setup the listening event for hovering over these newly created li's.

```
    $('.emails').on('mouseover',$('li'),function(){
                    alert('this is an email');
    });
```

hover doesnt trigger after ajax fires. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.comms').on('mouseover', 'li.emails', function(){
   alert('this is an email');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `.emails` elements get replaced so you would need to bind the hover action again or use dynamic binding:

```
$('.comms').on('mouseover', '.emails', function(){
    alert('this is an email');
});
```